# Function passing values into input boxes PHP using mysqli

Tags: php, html

Pretty much what I want to do is get ID from database and pass that ID values into input boxes so I can re-edit them when clicking on edit button

```
<td><a class= "waves-effect waves-light btn" href="http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/includes/evidencija.inc.php?edit='.$row['evidencijaId'].'"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></a></td>
```

This is my icon href to get Id and pass it to evidencija.inc.php

```
if(isset($_GET["edit"])){
    $id = $_GET["edit"];
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/robinzonlucica/public/includes/dbh.inc.php';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/robinzonlucica/public/includes/funkcije.inc.php';
    
    izmijeniEvidenciju($conn,$id);
}
else{
    header("location: http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/evidencija.php");
    exit();
}
```

This is my evidencija.inc.php part to get id from that row and there is izmijeniEvidenciju($conn,$id); function to edit values for given edit=id

```
function izmijeniEvidenciju($conn, $id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM evidencija WHERE evidencijaId = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("location: http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/evidencija.php?error=stmtgreska");
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}
```

That is my function to get data  I want data to show in [input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMPyy.png) not sure where I went wrong I am very confused

```
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
echo '<h2 class ="center-align evidencijanaslov">Evidencija</h2>
<div class="row">
<form action="http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/includes/evidencija.inc.php" class="col s12 registerforma" method="post">
<div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="ime" type="text" class="validate" name="ime">
          <label for="last_name">Ime Turista</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="ime" type="text" class="validate" name="prezime" >
          <label for="last_name">Prezime turista</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="ime" type="text" class="validate" name="oib">
          <label for="last_name">OIB Turista</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input type=text name="datum" id="datum" class="datepicker">
        <label for="datum">Datum odlaska</label>
        </div>
        </div>
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light gumbsalji" type="submit" name="submit">Upiši</button>
    </div>
    </form>';
    
  }
```

This is html input

Comment: Is that the complete `izmijeniEvidenciju` function? It doesn't return any values. Where is the code that uses the result of this function to insert the values into html?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes it is the full function not sure how to pass results into text boxes of html should I need to create echo into values I am sure but not sure what values I am def sure that I am missing something there

Comment: `http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/includes/evidencija.inc.php`- Why do you have links in the frontend, to URLs in which both a folder name as well as part of the file name strongly indicate, that this is an _include_ file? Those are usually not meant to be called directly in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe I am using links like that cause I had problems with xampp directories it bugged for me so i found this working :/

Comment: So what sense does it make to create such a structure in the first place, if you then violate it at will?

Comment: @CBroe What do you recommend me to do to repair this use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. or?