# Problem with return php to html on second page

Tags: php, html

Currently I am stuck when i click edit icon my page goes to 
http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/includes/evidencija.inc.php?edit=3 
It should insert data into my form

```
if(isset($_GET["edit"])){
    $id = $_GET["edit"];
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/robinzonlucica/public/includes/dbh.inc.php';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/robinzonlucica/public/includes/funkcije.inc.php';
    izmijeniEvidenciju($conn,$id);

}
```

This form should call function izmijeniEvidenciju($conn,$id);

This is function code

```
function izmijeniEvidenciju($conn, $id) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM evidencija WHERE evidencijaId = ?;";
   $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
   if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
       header("location: http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/evidencija.php?error=stmtgreska");
       exit();
   }
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $id);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   return $row;
   mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

And this is my html part form that values should be written in after clicking edit but when i click icon to edit it goes on blank page and stays like that

```
<?php
 include_once 'header.php';
 require_once 'includes/funkcije.inc.php';
 require_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
?>

<section class="evidencija">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
$editrow = izmijeniEvidenciju($conn, $id);
echo '<h2 class ="center-align evidencijanaslov">Evidencija</h2>
<div class="row">
<form action="http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/includes/evidencija.inc.php" class="col s12 registerforma" method="post">
<div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="ime" type="text" class="validate" name="ime" value="'.$editrow['evidencijaTuristIme'].'">
          <label for="last_name">Ime Turista</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="ime" type="text" class="validate" name="prezime" value="'.$editrow['evidencijaTuristPrezime'].' ">
          <label for="last_name">Prezime turista</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="ime" type="text" class="validate" name="oib" value="'.$editrow['evidencijaTuristOIB'].'">
          <label for="last_name">OIB Turista</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input type=text name="datum" id="datum" class="datepicker" value="'.$editrow['evidencijaTuristDatumOdlaska'].'">
        <label for="datum">Datum odlaska</label>
        </div>
        </div>
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light gumbsalji" type="submit" name="submit">Upiši</button>
    </div>
    </form>';
    
  }
  else {
      echo '<h1>Prijavite se kako bi vidjeli evidenciju</h1>';
  }
```

I am getting that $id variable is not declared too don't know where I went wrong PS hardcoding $id with id from table inputs values into form :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function passing values into input boxes PHP using mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024159/function-passing-values-into-input-boxes-php-using-mysqli)

Comment: No, not really there is different problem @Dharman

Comment: Did you start the session?

Comment: note that in the function `izmijeniEvidenciju()` the last line won't be executed, the functions exits on `return`

Comment: @Cid I have session for login so it should work if you are logged in I am sure :/

Comment: Delete part works for me but edit part doesn't :/

Comment: are you getting anything doing `var_dump($_SESSION);`, just **before** `if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) {` ?

Comment: @Cid array(2) { ["korisniciId"]=> int(3) ["username"]=> string(4) "test" } this is what I am getting I am logged in as user called test

Comment: This is what it looks like there when errors show
https://i.gyazo.com/faa1f99f5dd80bdfe71a40fea7d2b151.png

Comment: Lots of notices there. Here's a general [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) you might want to read to get rid of those.

Comment: Yes the problem is that they display only when I don't hardcode $id in html part not sure how to pass that id tru edit=# cause it won't pass it